# TCP Bytearray doesnt work, but Printerwriter works?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Currently I'm trying to communicate between from Client to Server and vice versa in Java.

So as of now, I tried with the following

Attempt 1) Trying to send through string in bytearray form.

Client

```
OutputStream os = clientSock.getOutputStream();
byte[] sndMsg = new String("test").getBytes();
os.write(sndMsg);
os.flush();
```

Server

```
InputStream is = serverChild.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

String rcvRequest = br.readLine();
System.out.println(rcvRequest);
```

Apparently when it does not print out test.

Attempt 2)
However, when I change the code from Client side to

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSock.getOutputStream()));
out.println("test");
out.flush();
```

It works. Why is this so? Is it any way I can use attempt 1 to try and send byte array over and receive it as a string in the server side? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BufferedReader.readLine waits for NewLine character, you should add it to "test" in attempt 1. println in attempt 2 adds it automatically

Comment: Hm? Hi @Evgeniy Dorofeev I did it in line 2 of attempt 1 If i am not mistaken.

Comment: it should be new String("test\n").getBytes();